# Play 2 scala route controller bytecode is not the same as all the other bytecode

Tags: scala, heroku, proguard, playframework-2.0

I'm running on Mint 12, Play 2.0, and trying to get Proguard to work, because my Heroku slug is too big.

So, I'm using the [xsbt proguard plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin), and it barfs because ProGuard doesn't like the bytecode format, 51.  It's ProGuard 4.7, so it's supposed to work with 51, but it doesn't:

```
[error] {file:/(some path)/*:proguard: java.io.IOException: Can't read
[/(that path)/target/scala-2.9.1/(my app)_2.9.1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]
(Can't process class [controllers/routes$ref.class]
(Unsupported version number [51.0] for class format))
```

So, I look at what's in the jar, and almost all the lines are like this:

```
./controllers/Application.class:  compiled Java class data, version 49.0 (Java 1.5)
```

But the router looks like this:

```
./controllers/routes.class:       compiled Java class data, version 51.0
```

What would make the router choose a different -target than everything else?

I'm using the JDK7 that comes with Mint, if that matters:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.0) (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using ProGuard 4.7. It supports Java 7 (class file version 51.0). It also produces a different error message for unsupported Java versions. ProGuard prints out its version number when it runs, so it should be easy to check.

Comment: Bleah, you're right.  I had an older plugin version, because I blindly followed the [directions](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin).  Specifying the latest one fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`routes.class` has different bytecode format because it is compiled by javac from auto generated

```
target/scala-{version}/src_managed/controllers/routes.java
```

while other class files are produced by scala compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was that; I poked through the Play code and couldn't find anywhere that the -target option was set, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to reduce the slug size of Play 2 apps on Heroku:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/R_BbIomWsqI/discussion

Comment: Well, yeah, I'm [doing that](https://github.com/enrich/heroku-buildpack-scala), and it helps, but my slug is still (slightly) over the limit.  I am also concerned with the dyno size on Heroku, so I'm moving to EC2 instances.

Comment: Well, it's several things.  Running "sbt stage" produces about 175MB.  There's a fat static submodule in public, 27MB.  The app jar in target/staged is 21MB.  All of target/staged is 65MB altogether, and there's 51MB more in target/scala-2.9.1, so target is 115MB. There are code submodules in modules, 28MB.  I could probably shrink the static public submodule most easily, but I'm not sure what else to attack.  ... oh, actually looking more closely at it, is there any chance that my submodule repos are somehow being included?  Those are pretty big fractions of the submodule size.

Comment: What do you mean by "static submodule"?

Comment: sorry, i mean a git submodule that lives in public, full of javascript.

Comment: Ok.  But 27MB of JavaScript?  Also I believe the `public` dir contents might be getting duplicated into a compiled JAR.

Comment: ah, good pointer, you're right, the compiled jar includes the local git repo (i.e. ".git").  :-(  is there a simple way to exclude it?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure.  I'd probably switch whatever is in that git submodule into a JAR dependency.  But then you'd need to get the dependency into a local repo for Heroku to resolve it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies